# Make android keyboard auto popup in dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-keypad

I have a dialogue which prompts a user to enter in a 4 digit pin.

I would like for the keyboard to automatically be displayed when this dialog fragment popup is shown,

I have tried the following but I have not come right

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/entercode_dialog_editText_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This for Showing KeyBoard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getactivity().
                             getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

solutiuon1:

```
if(imm != null){
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

solution2:

```
if(imm != null){
imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
}
```

where ed is your edittext

---

**one more solution (not tried yet)**
after inializing dialog

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Where do i run this? In the dialog fragment?

Comment: 'getSystemService()' does not work in a fragment? Whats my alternative

Comment: ohh sorry for fragment you need getactivity() as context...see my updated answer

Comment: Ok good its working now, however there is a small issue, It loads the keyboard, and then as the dialogue loads the keyboard goes away.

Comment: i think this is better solution:
override onActivityCreated in your dialogfragment and put this

getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57141/discussion-between-kalpesh-lakhani-and-zapnologica).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To appear the soft keyboard , you can use

```
 EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);  
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To close it you can use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope Can Help You